# BJT circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

I've been doing this question for quite a long time, can someone explain to me why b would be different from part d, and what im doing wrong from part b and c?
[image: partb]

[image: partc]

[image: question]

Comment: Constant voltage drop  model you can ignore Rz.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the node I've labeled as \$V_B\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBtb8Dm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's no need for nodal analysis of it for the constant voltage drop model. It's simply true that \$V_B=-11\:\textrm{V}\$. From this it is easy to work out \$V_O\$, then \$I_{R_L}\$, and then \$I_B\$ from that. That's (b).

But for the case where you have to use the incremental model, you need a model for the zener. This is generally of the form:

$$V_Z = V_{Z0} + I_Z\cdot R_Z$$

Given your zener specifications, and treating \$I_Z\$ as positive, this works out to \$V_{Z0}=10.816\:\textrm{V}\$. We also know that \$V_B=-V_Z\$, of course.

Now, nodal analysis helps out.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_B}{R_{BZ}}+\frac{V_B}{R_Z}+I_B&=\frac{-V_{Z0}}{R_Z}+\frac{V_I}{R_{BZ}}
\end{align*}$$

But we also know: \$I_B=\frac{V_B+700\:\textrm{mV}}{\beta R_L}\$

Therefore:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_B}{R_{BZ}}+\frac{V_B}{R_Z}+ \frac{V_B+700\:\textrm{mV}}{\beta R_L}&=\frac{-V_{Z0}}{R_Z}+\frac{V_I}{R_{BZ}}\\\\
\frac{V_B}{R_{BZ}}+\frac{V_B}{R_Z}+\frac{V_B}{\beta R_L}&=\frac{-V_{Z0}}{R_Z}+\frac{V_I}{R_{BZ}}-\frac{700\:\textrm{mV}}{\beta R_L}\\\\
V_B&=\left[\frac{-V_{Z0}}{R_Z}+\frac{V_I}{R_{BZ}}-\frac{700\:\textrm{mV}}{\beta R_L}\right]\cdot\bigg[R_{BZ}\mid\mid R_Z \mid\mid \beta R_L\bigg]
\end{align*}$$

Note that if you calculate this out, you will find that \$V_Z\approx -10.9816\:\textrm{V}\$, which is not the same as \$-11\:\textrm{V}\$. From here you can work out a slightly different value for \$I_B\$, I think.

Answer (score 0):

For parts c) and d), try the following.

Step 1) Using nodal analysis, derive an equation whose terms include the unknown voltage at node \$V_Z\$ in Figure 1 below. *[Hint: Apply KCL at the \$V_Z\$ node.]* Note that "\$I_B\$" will be one of the terms in your nodal analysis equation. *(You'll replace the \$I_B\$ term in the next step.)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdvTxv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Figure 1.

Step 2) In your nodal analysis equation from step 1, replace \$I_B\$ with an equivalent term that includes \$V_O\$ (whose value is unknown) and other terms whose values are known:

$$
I_{RL}=I_E=I_C+I_B=\beta I_B+I_B=I_B(\beta +1)=V_O/R_L
\\[0.2in]
\rightarrow I_B=\frac{V_O}{R_L(\beta +1)}
$$

Step 3) You'll need a second equation to solve for the two unknowns \$V_Z\$ and \$V_O\$:

$$
V_O=V_Z+V_{EB}
$$

Step 4) You now have two equations and two unknowns \$V_Z\$ and \$V_{O}\$. Using the method of *simultaneous equations* solve for the two unknowns \$V_Z\$ and \$V_{O}\$.